# Adding a shapefile with a double-click to an opened project in QGIS in Nautilus on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, mac, file-association

On my Ubuntu computer, I have GIS file types like `.shp` associated with QGIS in Nautilus. When I double click on a `.shp` while I have a QGIS project open, **it opens a new project** in a **new instance** of QGIS, **even if I have a project open**.

On my Mac, if I have QGIS running and I double-click a `.shp` in Finder, **the file will be added to the existing project**.

Other files associated with other programs will open in a running instance rather than a new instance: text files will open in a new tab in my text editor, for example.

**I'd like QGIS to add the shapefile in my opened project instead of launching a new instance**. How can I do that ?

Comment: I think this question is on-topic for GIS Stack Exchange because it pertains specifically to a GIS software package, and the difference between that package on one OS vs another. Asking this question on a site like AskUbuntu would not be likely to find many other users familiar with the package. Furthermore, the question directly relates to common GIS workflow.

Comment: I edited your question differently to help you reopening your question : I supposed the real question is not why it doesn open in the current project but **how to achieve what you really want to do**.

Comment: Could you check the file association ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/369967/how-do-i-set-the-default-file-association-in-ubuntu-nautilus-to-something-that-i - just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. I see the same behaviour with dolphin (different desktop) on different distro. Looking at `qgis --help`, nothing sticks out as useful and this is what the underlying system would use.

But there is a simple workaround. Drag'n'drop the file from your file manager into qgis and it will open as a new layer in the existing, open project.